# How are URLs with ../ formatted?

Tags: url, url-routing

I've experimented with URLs of this format:

```
https://A.com/B/../C
```

As far as I can see, they are always reformatted:

```
https://A.com/B/../C becomes https://A.com/C
https://A.com/B/C/../C/D becomes https://A.com/B/C/D
```

Is this a part of the URL standard, or does it depend on the browser or server?

Here is an example you can try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/../ask/../../questions/ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's part of [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)

In the [path definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) we can read

> The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are
> defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
> are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
> (Section 4.2) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
> tree of names.

And [later](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) we can see how these relative segments are processed,

> ```
>              [...]
>               else
>                  T.path = merge(Base.path, R.path);
>                  T.path = remove_dot_segments(T.path);
>               endif;
>              [...]
> ```

and how the relative part `../C` will get [merged](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.3) with the *base* `https://A.com/B` into `https://A.com/../C`

> return a string consisting of the reference's path component
> appended to all but the last segment of the base URI's path (i.e.,
> excluding any characters after the right-most "/" in the base URI
> path, or excluding the entire base URI path if it does not contain
> any "/" characters).

and further how the dots `/../` will get [replaced by `/`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2.4)

> [...]

> - C. if the input buffer begins with a prefix of "/../" or "/..",
>   where ".." is a complete path segment, then replace that
>   prefix with "/" in the input buffer and remove the last
>   segment and its preceding "/" (if any) from the output
>   buffer; [...]

So we can get the final `https://A.com/C`